# LD+JSON - Use for SameAs for a Product

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

Assume you have an eCommerce site from which you sell some product.  You also sell that product on Amazon.  What would be the SEO implications of using the `sameAs` property in your eCommerce site's ld+json to link to your Amazon URL as well?  Is this a valid practice and would you gain anything by it?

For example:

```
{
   "@context":"https://schema.org/",
   "@type":"Product",
   "sameAs":[AMAZON URL HERE],
   "name":"My Product",
   "image":"myproductimage.jpg",
   "description":"my description",
   "brand":{
      "@type":"Thing",
      "name":"Brand"
   },
   "sku":"SKU",
   "mpn":"MPN",
   "offers":{ ... }
}
```

N.B. I had previously asked this question here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16016/ldjson-use-for-sameas-product since I tagged it as `linked-data` and that tag suggested posting there instead.  But, I am not sure if it actually makes more sense to ask here since I've also seen several `ld-json` questions.

Answer (score 1):

**[Description of this property from Schema](https://schema.org/sameAs)**:

> URL of a reference Web page that unambiguously indicates the item's
>   identity.

We discuss activity in the digital domain can, therefore, make sense to check the Digital identity value of Wikipedia:

> A digital identity is information on an entity used by computer
>   systems to represent an external agent. That agent may be a person,
>   organization, application, or device. ISO/IEC 24760-1 defines identity
>   as "set of attributes related to an entity".

In my humble opinion, the web page for selling your product on Amazon can hardly be called digital identification.

Information from Wikipedia, from Wikidata, from DBpedia and similar resources are more suitable for product identification.

Comment: I agree. I'd also add that a single product sold in multiple places would typically be listed under `offers`. That seems to me like the expectation for this scenario.